# User agent check for Windows device

Tags: apex, windows8

I'm using something similar to the following code snippet in my Apex controller to check if someone is accessing my website from an iPhone or Android phone.

```
userAgent.contains('iPhone') || ( userAgent.contains('Android') && userAgent.contains('Mobile'));
```

Can I use something similar to check if someone is using a Windows device?

Comment: This should help: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/

Answer (score -1):

According to the version of categorizr I have on hand, the following detects windows mobile:

userAgent.contains('Windows.NT.5')
I'm not sure if a more recent list needs applying